# Forwarding params in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, std

I have some class and wrapper around it. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class inner
{
public:
    void f(T& v) { std::cout<<"lvalue: "<<v<<std::endl;}
    void f(T&& v) { std::cout<<"rvalue: "<<v<<std::endl;}
};

template<typename T>
class wrapper
{
public:
    template<typename _T>
    void f(_T&& v) { i.f(std::forward<T>(v)); } //(1)

private:
    inner<T> i;
};

int main()
{
    wrapper<std::string> c;
    //inner<std::string> c;

    c.f("r");

    std::string s = "l";
    c.f(s);
}
```

In the case when `c` is `inner` output is correct:

```
rvalue: r
lvalue: l
```

But when `c` is `wrapper` output is not correct:

```
rvalue: r
rvalue: l
```

Why l-value became r-value?

And what the difference if `wrapper`'s `f` definition on line `(1)` would be:

```cpp
    template<typename _T>
    void f(_T v) { i.f(std::forward<T>(v)); } //without &&
```

Comment: `std::forward<_T>(v)`. Also, you are using a reserved identifier.

Comment: @T.C.: Answers don't go in comments

Comment: @T.C. I thought using `_T` and `T` would only cause different places of same error on type mismatch. Why it cause conversion lvalue to rvalue? And what about second question and `&&`? Removing them does not affects anything.

Comment: `_T` is a reserved identifier.  Its use makes your entire program ill-formed.  As a simple rule, avoid starting identifiers with `_`, and don't have `__` anywhere in an identifier, and you'll avoid hitting (almost all?) identifiers reserved by the standard.  (The actual rules reserve fewer identifiers than that, but this is a simple sufficient rule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're doing:

```
template<typename _T>
void f(_T&& v) { i.f(std::forward<T>(v)); } //(1)
                                  ^
                                  T, not _T
```

You're always just using `T`, not the *deduced* type of `v`. For added clarity, you're actually doing:

```
template <typename _T>
void f(_T&& v) {
    i.f(std::forward<std::string>(v));
}
```

And the type of `std::forward<std::string>(v)` is `string&&`.

For your second question:

```
template<typename _T>
void f(_T v) { i.f(std::forward<T>(v)); } //without &&
```

Since `_T` will never deduce as a reference type here, `std::forward<T>(v)` will be equivalent to `std::move(v)` - it's just a cast to rvalue reference.

Comment: What about `void f(_T& v) { i.f(std::forward<T>(v)); }` case? Same behavior.

Comment: @lorond Again, `_T` vs `T`. If you correct that, it'll just be a no-op - `std::forward<_T>(v)` is just `v` for lvalue references.

Comment: My bad. With `&&` and `_T` works fine. But `void f(_T& v) { i.f(std::forward<_T>(v)); }` and `void f(_T v) { i.f(std::forward<_T>(v)); }` both producing rvalue. Why? I thought it must be lvalue in both cases since there is no `&&` rvalue definition.

Comment: @lorond Sorry I misspoke the first time. If you just have `f(_T& v)`, then `_T` will deduce as `std::string`, so your `forward` will forward an rvalue reference. The difference is that in `f(_T&& v)`, for an lvalue reference, `_T` deduces as `std::string&`.